# Exist a nugget package or assembly called Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Components.Prerendering?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm started to migrate my netcore project from 2.2 to 3.0 preview 8, when I tried to start it (asp.net core project), specifically adding Mvc in the startup class:

```
services.AddMvc();
```

an error is throwed:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Components.Prerendering, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, RuntimeAssembly assemblyContext, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.<>c.<GetApplicationPartAssemblies>b__8_0(ApplicationPartAttribute name)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__16.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateDefaultParts(String entryAssemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.GetApplicationPartManager(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllersCore(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllersWithViewsCore(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllersWithViews(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvc(IServiceCollection services)
   at Catalog.Api.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in <path to source code>:line 76
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Build>b__0(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Catalog.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in <path to source code> 27
```

I was looking for a while but seems to be no one has this error, and the package doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out,

I was using the last image of Asp.Net Core

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core-nightly/aspnet:3.0.0-preview9
```

but an older version of the SDK

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0.100-preview8
```

My solution was to move the Asp.Net Core to preview8 and now all is working as espected.

Answer (score 1):

I migrate to preview9 and I have this error on my debian server

I pipeline a ubuntu zip with dll to my debian server

There is no problem doing this with preview 8

I found this:

- https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/pull/12714/files

and this;

- https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12245

**Proposed Product Changes**

These changes can take place as late as Preview 9 - but earlier is always better

We should remove the functionality for stateful-prerendering from the server. We're not recommending it for use in any production scenario, and so we should remove the functionality.

The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Components.Prerendering package can be removed.

The RenderStaticComponentAsync methods should be renamed to RenderComponentAsync.

Various implementation pieces can be cleaned up as-desired. We can't predict right now if we'll bring back the same feature in the same way, so the cleanest thing to do would be to remove all of the unneeded functionality.

**Edit:**

With the RC it's work

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14068

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is caused in some scenarios where sdk and runtime are used from diferent preview version. In my case the solution was straightfoward, change the sdk and runtime to the same preview version and unistalling the old one (just in case).

Comment: on my debian vps i don't have dotnet runtime, only sdk (i run by "dotnet mydll.dll").

with preview 9 (and source in preview8 it dosn't work), but if i downgrade to sdk preview 8 no prob